# How to check datatype from data of the file

Tags: python

I made a function which checks if data can be converted into int or float using other functions:

```
def inputData(txt, indexOfFile):  # function that inputs data in the file
    print("*" * 10, "What do you want to do?", "*" * 10)
    print(" 1. Work with existing data \n 2. Add new data \n 3. Delete data \n 4. Go back")
    # printTxtFile() #function that prints txt file, but rn it doesnt even matter
    #list(data) = txt
    indexOfOperation = int(input()) #Выбор действия - работа с сущ данными - добавить новые данные - удалить данные - вернуться в главное меню some russian or something
    
    if(indexOfFile == 1): # based on user input it will open one of 3 files
        filePath = "buildings.txt"
        types = [0, 1, 1, 1] #array that declare which datatypes are in this file in each columns: 0 is string, 1 is int, 2 is float
    elif(indexOfFile == 2):
        filePath = "apartments.txt"
        types = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    elif(indexOfFile == 3): 
        filePath = "apartment owners.txt"
        types = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
    else:
        filePath = "buildings.txt"
        types = [0, 1, 1, 1]
        
    with open(filePath, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        num_rows = len(txt) #number of columns
        num_columns = len(txt[0]) #number of rows (it's made strange, I know, but it is what it is)

        if indexOfOperation == 1: #this checks if we want to work with existing data
            print("Which row will you redact?")
            choise = int(input()) #entering number of the row
            printTxtFile(txt) #printing txt file

            for i in range(len(txt[choise - 1])):
                tmp = input("Enter your data: ").replace(' ', '_') #replacing spaces with underscores
                ok, k = check_type(tmp, types[i]) #ok checks if datatype was entered correctly, k is data
                while(not ok): #hard check
                    print("Must be a number! Reenter!")
                    tmp = input("Enter your data: ").replace(' ', '_')
                    ok, k = check_type(tmp, types[i])
                txt[choise][i] = k #entering data in the array

            for i in range(num_rows): #entering data from array to txt file
                for j in range(num_columns):
                    f.writelines(str(txt[i][j]) + "  ")
                if i != num_rows -1:
                    f.writelines("\n")

            f.close()
```

There are functions that check data types:

```
def str_to_int(s):
    try:
        k = int(s)
    except ValueError:
        ok = False
        k = 0
        #print('ValueError: не удалось преобразовать строку в float: ')
    else:
        ok = True
        #print('Успех, нет ошибок!')
    return ok, k

def str_to_float(s):
    try:
        k = float(s)
    except ValueError:
        ok = False
        k = 0
        #print('ValueError: не удалось преобразовать строку в float: ')
    else:
        ok = True
        #print('Успех, нет ошибок!')
    return ok, k
# 0 -str 1-int 2-float

def check_type(s, tp):
    k = 0
    ok = True
    if (tp == 0):
        return True, s
    if (tp == 1):
        return str_to_int(s)
    if (tp == 2):
        return str_to_float(s)
```

I cannot check datatype in textfile, which uploads in the array as string.

How do I check datatype from the data of the file?

Comment: a minimal working example would be great

Comment: The file contains text, period. All you can do is read that text and determine if you can *parse* the text as the desired data type. (That's pretty much what you are doing with user input: the "file" you are reading from is just standard input, in this case provided by the terminal emulator instead of a file on disk.)